# Phonegap 2.9.0 Filesystem is not available

Tags: javascript, mobile, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm doing a mobile app using the Phonegap 2.9.0 compiling through the Phonegap Build.

I did some tests with geolocation and worked fine. But now I'm trying to write/read files. So, i'm using the sample code provided in the Phonegap documentation.

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
```

And it throws a error (FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR) everytime. And if i try to access the fileSystem it's undefined.

In the config.xml file. I request for the File plugin.

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/media"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/storage"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
```

I searched a lot, in another questions, and any helped me.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have `<script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>` referenced in your head tags?

Are you sure you are waiting for deviceready to be called by using `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);` and not trying to call the file API until the callback is referenced?

I know that with Phonegap Build 3.0 you need to include `<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.core.file" />` in your config.xml but that is only for 3.0. I dont know if there is anything else you need for 2.x

You really should go to Phonegap Build 3.0 if you can.

Comment: My code was inside a $(document).ready.
But i changed to addEventListener('deviceready') and it doesn't worked.